# LWJGL Camera stretches and shrinks shapes

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl, cube

I've been looking around and i couldn't find an answer to this but what I have done is create a cube / box and the camera will squash and stretch depending on where I am looking at. This all seems to resolve it self when the screen is perfectly square but when I'm using 16:9 it stretches and squashes the shapes. Is it possible to change this?

16:9
[image]

and this is 500px X 500px
[image]

As a side question would it be possible to change the color of background "sky"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL uses a cube [-1,1]^3 to represent the frustum in normalized device coordinates. The Viewport transform strechtes this in x and y direction to [0,width] and [0,height]. So to get the correct output aspect ratio, you have to take the viewport dimensions into account when transfroming the vertices into clip space. Usually, this is part of the projection matrix. The old fixed-function [`gluPerspective()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) function has a parameter to directly create a frustum for a given aspect ratio. As you do not show any code, it is hard to suggest what you actually should change, but it should be quite easy, as it boils down to a simple scale operation along x and y.

To the side question: That color is defined by the values the color buffer is set to when clearing the it. You can set the color via [`glClearColor()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearColor.xml).